# Blender and Youtube seen to be unable to run at same time

Tags: error

First of all, sorry if this isn't the right place for posting, this is actually my first post here... Anyway, back to the problem:

Started some time ago, I can't exacly remember when, but now it got worst. What happens is that when Blender is running (even a new file without any interation yet) any Youtube or web video enters a "loading loop" and never plays, but the moment I close Blender it starts perfectly.

Well, sometimes I could manage to still watch the video by closing everything and running Blender software *BEFORE* starting the browser and them open the video, but now it seens that Blender stops responding when I open the video and I can't figure out why!

---

**My setup is:**

Blender version: 2.82a

OS: Ubuntu Linux 19.10

CPU: Intel Core i7-7700HQ @ 2.80GHz x8

GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX1060

Comment: This isn't an 'answer' but I have also noticed some issues running Youtube in a browser alongside Blender. I have noticed the problem you mentioned, where it enters a 'loading loop' but also sometimes it crashes Blender - simply freezes, requiring a reboot. (I have 'answered' because I'm a newbie and cannot add a comment, hope it helps to move things along.)

Comment: Would you be able to tell about your computers performance during this. I don't think it's a hardware issue but still check. I don't seem to have this issue even with multiple apps using the internet in the background so report it as a bug.

Comment: Well, I guess it's probably a bug, the rest of my applications seens to be normal, so I guess it's not hardware related too...